# css overflow:hidden causing extra bottom margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row with form fields and labels. I'm attempting to achieve an ellipsis effect if the label text wraps beyond the width of it's input. My css seems to be working correctly however I'm getting an extra bottom margin when applying the `overflow: hidden` style to the label. Does anyone know the reason for this and how to solve it?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Carrier</label>
             <input class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="ellipsis">Type of Coverage (PPO, HMO, Indemity, deductibles/copays)</label>
             <input class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Period in Effect</label>
             <input class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/385160qe/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with overflow: hidden but with display: inline-block of the label element:

```
label {
    display: **inline-block;**
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

change it to display: block and it will fix it.

```
label {
    display: **block;**
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Another fix is to vertical align that particular label, .ellipsis, to bottom instead of overwriting default class of bootstrap:

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:bottom
}
```

Depends which solution fits you best.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bootstrap default. I'll override it.

Comment: Check the second solution from the updated answer for a new solution without overwriting boostrap default.

Comment: Thank you, I was just able to add `display: block` to my `.ellipsis` class and it did the trick!

Comment: I'm glad if I could help, don't forget to mark the answer ;)